# Calendário mostrando somente o mês e o ano no react native

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, calendar

Estou desenvolvendo um app com react native e queria que no calendário mostrasse somente o mês e o ano. Estou tentando com a dependência react-native-calendars mas não tive sucesso.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Calendar } from 'react-native-calendars'

class ReleasesScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Calendar
                    hideExtraDays={true}
                    hideDayNames={true}
                    theme={{
                        calendarBackground: '#2195F2',
                        arrowColor: '#fff',
                        monthTextColor: '#fff'
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Meu app esta exatamente assim: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhFK0.png

e queria deixar dessa forma, sem o component de dias: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHsdv.png

Se alguém puder me dá uma solução ou outra dependência que faco isso. Grato!

Comment: também gostaria de saber

Comment: Olhando a documentação, não vi que o componente tem a opção de usar somente meses. Melhor você procurar um componente que te dê a opção

Comment: Já tentou essa Biblioteca? Eu acho melhor você tentar outras bibliotecas
https://github.com/react-native-community/datetimepicker

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer um array com os meses e mostrar em um flatlist, exemplo :
const meses = ["Janeiro","Fevereiro"...]
pra mostrar o ano é só você utilizar o new Date() e o moment, o new Date te da horas, meses e ano, veja mais sobre ele, e utilize o moment para formatar o ano e mostrar como você quiser e faz duas funções, uma de incrementar o ano e outra de decrementar o ano.
exemplo :

Ano : 2020
Meses : Janeiro, Fevereiro....
botao proximo ano : Ano + 1;
botao Voltar ano : Ano - 1;